# MacBook pro boot's to wrong OS after waking up from Safe Sleep

Tags: sleep-wake, startup, unix, dual-boot, efi

I am dual booting Ubuntu and OS X Mavericks on my MacBook pro 9,2. I am using the [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) boot manager, since I was told that I should use it to dual boot OS X and Linux (I could have used rEFIt, but it seems to be no longer maintained).

Every time I boot up my MacBook after OS X has gone into Safe Sleep, instead of booting into OS X (and thus restoring everything that I was doing), it boots into Ubuntu. That's annoying, but I acknowledge mistakes happen, but when I reboot back into OS X, everything is gone.

It will be great if there was a way to restore the state before OS X has gone into Safe Sleep, and better yet have the MacBook *actually* reboot into OS X after a Safe Sleep.

Comment: Have you checked the "Startup Disk" preference in System Preferences? I'm not familiar enough with rEFInd to know if it would override that, but perhaps when in Safe Sleep mode, OS X still has 'boot control' and goes off of your startup disk preference. (If this works, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.)

Comment: On the Startup Disk preference, I only see one volume, and it's Macintosh HD. I'm guessing the reason why the preference is able to view Macintosh HD is because it is formatted in HFS+, where as the partition where Ubuntu is installed is formatted as EXT4, which is a format that OS X doesn't recognize, and hence why it's not in the preference.

Comment: I think it's a problem with rEFInd, or a problem with EFI (which I really hope it's not the latter).

Comment: When you open SD pref, is the disk highlighted/selected? If not, click on it, then see if anything changes.

Comment: Yep, it's selected. Or [so it seems](http://imgur.com/nCqLB1F). There is a blue highlighting on the text, which was not done by me. It was already there when I navigated to the "Startup Disk" preference.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your rEFInd config file? Can you post it here? (http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html)